# ObjectID not showing for AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId technical profile

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm a bit stumped and not sure where to go from here.

I am trying to extract the object ID via B2C custom policies in Azure B2C. I have an Entra ID technical profile called `AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError`, which refers to another technical profile. See below:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId" PartnerClaimType="alternativeSecurityId" Required="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
</TechnicalProfile>

<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <!-- <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
  </OutputClaims> -->
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

From my user journey, I'm trying to perform a print of the the object ID claim (via OpenIdConnect protocol) but is not showing up. I know the social account exists and the technical profile is pulling that info because the other claims in the output are shown (such as the `userPrincipalName`, `otherMails`, etc.). These claims are not being populated the in previous steps because there's only two user journey steps prior to this and it's not modifying those claims. Also I can see in the app insights, the claims bag at this point is missing the object ID.

Any ideas why the `objectId` can't be extracted?